# react-apollo Query: Correct way to get the data from a <Query> Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-apollo

I'm trying to get the data from my Query component into something I can render. I have this function that performs the query, and my component's render method calls this function. My question is, how do I get the data into something I can use?

Query function:

```
protected queryFoos() {
  const { match: { params } } = this.props;
  const projectId  = params.projectId;
  const { query, dataKey } = fooGql.list;

  return (
    <Query query={query} variables={{ [RouteId.Project]: projectId }}>

      {({ data, error, loading }: QueryResult) => {
        if (loading) { return <div>Loading...</div>; }
        if (error) { return <div>{error}</div>; }

        const listFoos = plainToClassFromExist(new Foo(), data);
        const variablesList = data.listFoos.items;
        // this.setState({ foos: foosList}); // <= this doesn't work

        return listFoos;
       }}

    </Query>
  )
}
```

And my component that calls the query function:

```js
...

state = {
  foos: [],
}

protected renderContent(project: Project) {
  // query all foos related to the project

  return (
    {project &&
          <Grid container alignItems="stretch">
            <Grid item xs={12}<Typography>Foos</Typography></Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                {this.queryFoos()}
                <EntityTable entities={this.state.foos}/>
              </Grid>
          </Grid>
       </Grid>
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you try `{console.log(this.queryFoos())}`?

Comment: I just tried that, it returns some Symbol object. My thought was to set the local set state from with in query.

Comment: What about you return `data` and then console log that?

Comment: Went with a different approach. Used the store.client.query method to grab the values, and called it from componentDidMount.

Answer (score 0):

The `<Query>` component is meant to provide the data in the form of render props pattern, so it should go like

```
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    <Query query={query} variables={{ [RouteId.Project]: projectId }}>
      {({ data, error, loading }: QueryResult) => {
        // ... processing data into listFoos ...
        return
          loading ? <div>Loading</div>
          : error ? <div>{error}</div>
          : <EntityTable entities={listFoos} />;
      }}
    </Query>
  </Grid>
```

... setting state from a component leveraging render props pattern is an extra work and if I'd really need that, I'd considered a different pattern, e.g. `withQuery` HOC over the whole component (with which you'll have the results available as the component's prop, i.e. available in the whole component), providing query requirement props (e.g. variables) is a bit different then but the docs are quite clear on how to do that (generally these need to be props of the whole component); or the new `useQuery` hook.

If you just need to abstract out some query setup/result processing, you can create a component over the query:

```
const QueryFoos = (props: RequiredProps) => {
  // setup
  return (
    <Query query={query} variables={{ [RouteId.Project]: projectId }}>
      {({ data, error, loading }: QueryResult) => {
        // ... processing data into fooList ...
        return props.children({ data: fooList, error, loading });
      }}
    </Query>
  );
}
```

and use it like

```
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    <QueryFoos {...requiredProps}>
      {({ data, error, loading }) =>
        loading ? <div>Loading</div>
        : error ? <div>{error}</div>
        : <EntityTable entities={listFoos} />}
    </QueryFoos>
  </Grid>
```

which is pretty clear.